# Saving Seaborn Plot as PDF shifts colorbar frame

Tags: python, matplotlib, pdf, plot, seaborn

When saving my Seaborn heatmap plot with plt.savefig(sample.pdf), my colorbar frame gets distorted.
[image]

This distortion does not appear when using plt.show()

Is there a way to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the usual case, with more than 50 colors in the colormap, the colorbar pcolormesh output is rasterized to eliminate the artifacts that would otherwise appear when the pdf is rendered.

Rasterizing at low dpi gives bad resolution, so the colorbar interior doesn't coincide with the vector graphics of its outline.

Try to boost the dpi resolution argoument.

```
plt.savefig('your_file.pdf', dpi=200)
```

Comment: This is correct; it seems unintuitive to save with a dpi for a vector file format like PDF, but some artists are rasterized, and the dpi affects those artists.  In this case there is a small offset between pixel location and the axes.  (This is actually an unnecessary bug, but the PR to fix it never went in).

Comment: See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/17182